# Override VF/Lightning standard action defined

Tags: lightning-experience, redirect, button-overrides

We are in the process of migrating to Lightning. In our current solution we use on some objects the Visualforce override to view/edit the object record. For Lightning I would like to switch back the default view/edit actions.

So I was hoping to make both solutions work. VF overrides in classic view, default lightning record page for Lightning Experience.

What I tried so far:

1. Hoping for the  option to be available in the override section, not the case:

[image]
2. Creating a custom component (OpportunityRedirectTest) that uses lightning:navigation to navigate to the record id. But as expected, this just creates a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution was quite easy (if you would know).
Just create a lighting record page (not the default one), and magiclly an extra option pops up that allows you the select the record page to use as an override.

[image]